because a guy named John [had] pushed her
Sarah works at a hospital. Yesterday, during her shift, she had to assist her colleague in the emergency room. Today, she met up with her friend Lisa for a cup of coffee and told her about what happened yesterday:

During my shift yesterday, I had to go to the emergency room. A group of students from the drama college was sitting there anxiously while the doctor was examining their fellow student Becky. She'd fallen heavily and been knocked out because a guy named John had pushed her. After the doctor finished the examination, they were told that she had no major injuries.

Is the sentence correct both with and without the "had" in bold? If so, do you have a preference? Thanks in advance.

Using Past Perfect is a stylistic choice in your cited context. But you've already used it earlier in the same sentence (She'd fallen heavily...) so imho it's completely unnecessary to use it again, and doing so looks a bit clumsy to me. In general, you should avoid complex verb forms such as the perfect unless you know you need them, and here you don't.

In a quick oral recounting of such an incident, if the past perfect is used, it's unlikely that it would be used with every verb in the sentence, and the account is not likely to be as prolix. "Some guy named John had pushed her and she lost her balance and hit her head on the floor and was unconscious for a while."   But in a written narrative, especially one that involves more than one  period of past time, you might find the past perfect used throughout.

Could I have written     all this sentence in past simple because it seems pretty clear that the fall was before the examination

In general, a quick oral account might use the Past Perfect once (or even zero times) and then everything else would be simple past.
"Some guy named John had pushed her and she lost her balance and hit her head on the floor and was unconscious for a while."
From that perspective, repeating the Past Perfect is optional.
However in this specific case it seems to be following a written rather than spoken form, and there is a tendency to adhere to grammar rules more.  I would prefer the extra "had" in that sentence.
